# Fetch video from facebook news feed

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

every post in facebook news feed has property type. i need to fetch all posts with **type='video'** from facebook news feed and i cant find way to do this. 
Best result ive got is when i filter it with youtube like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?q=youtube&access_token=2227470867|2.DZCbXFjyGRSLWHSiklY1lg__.3600.1304269200.0-531926632|OiWpywOlwl1foPSth9_8RmrihTQ

please replace access_token in link with your own

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through a user's feed and throw out the items that aren't of type: video.

```
<script>
FB.api('/me/home/', {limit: 1000}, function(response)
{
    response.data.forEach(function(object)
    {
        if (object.type == 'video')
        {
            console.log(object.message);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: yeah i know, ive done something similar but i want to avoid fetching data which i dont need